# Understanding this sentence: と笑ってたがな

Tags: grammar, meaning, particles

I was playing Fire Emblem 5 and at the beginning of Chapter 2 there is a dialogue between two evil characters: one seems to be a priest called August and the other is a henchman called Bucks.

The henchman is telling the priest that their boss obtained some information from a villager through torture. The dialogue keeps going like this:

> 【アウグスト】
> 拷問か･･･▼
>
> 【バクス】
> そうだ
> かしらは拷問のやり方も
> あんたから教えられたといってたぜ▼
> さすがは
> 司祭を破門されるだけのことはある
> と笑ってたがな▼

I don't quite understand the last part of the dialogue. I've found an unofficial translation that goes like this:

> *August: “Torture…”*
>
> *Bucks: “Right. Our boss said you’re the one who taught him how to torture people. No wonder you were cast out of the order.”*

It seems to me that the "と笑ってたがな" part is missing. I'm not sure if "がな" here means something on the line of "I wish", so that the sentence would go "I would have liked to laugh about that"; but that makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The と笑ってた is the quotative と + the action of having laughed.

So, this henchman named Bucks is saying his boss laughed while saying "さすがは
司祭を破門されるだけのことはある"

The がな is equivalent to けど＋な. You can see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41790/meaning-of-%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AA-at-the-end-of-this-sentence) answer for more details.